# How does NRA spending compare to other major US lobbies?

Tags: united-states, lobbying, national-rifle-association

How does NRA spending compare to other US lobbies?  I often see the NRA portrayed as the most rich and powerful lobby in Washington, but I don't recall seeing any evidence to back this up.

Comment: You might want to specify that you are asking about lobbying spending.  It's been recently reported that they do a number of other things (such as gun safety and handling training).

Answer (score 13):

According to [Politifact](http://www.politifact.com/truth-o-meter/article/2017/oct/11/counting-up-how-much-nra-spends/), the NRA's claim of a minor amount of money spent during the 2017 elections *was minor* (comparatively). But the graph they produce show a clear trend of them looking at elections as a two year cycle, and 2017 happened to be their off year. In 2016 they [reportedly](http://www.mcclatchydc.com/news/politics-government/article177312006.html) spent $55 million, when some sources claimed it could have been high as $70 million, which would place them in the [#2 spot](https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/top.php?showYear=2016&indexType=s) only behind the US Chamber of Commerce (#3 if $55 million is more true, behind National Association of Realtors)<sup>✝</sup>. They have a much smaller amount of recurring yearly expenses that is mostly listed under the category of "Lobbying expenses", but their major source of spending in recent years goes to *Outside spending/Independent campaign expenditures*. Those expenditures are likely in the form of ad buys in targeted campaigns that are uncoordinated with an actual candidate's campaign (because that would be illegal).

This makes sense from the perspective of the NRA, since their overarching goal is resisting gun control *legislation*. The House of Representatives is re-elected every 2 years, so members are constantly campaigning and probably represents to the NRA the cheapest avenue for maintaining enough control to either (a) have enough influence to not even bring new gun control legislation for a vote, or (b) at least have enough influence to de-rail any negotiations on new gun control legislation either internally or through the media. Senators only have to stand for re-election every 6 years, so they have a chance to make other friends to take money from. From the NRA's perspective they're a bit more [slippery](https://www.npr.org/2018/02/22/588069939/sen-marco-rubio-backs-down-on-some-gun-ownership-restrictions-at-cnn-town-hall) to hold on to.

There's another possibility, and that's that the members of the NRA have a point and want to make sure that they are heard. The NRA at least *used* to be an organization about gun safety and training, which (in my opinion) is exactly the kind of organization we need to be spending money to solve the problem. Their [rhetoric](https://www.npr.org/2018/02/22/587911457/nra-leader-warns-conservatives-of-socialist-wave-in-wake-of-shooting) at the recent Conservative Political Action Conferance and the amount of response it has generated doesn't lead me to believe they will redirect those funds to less political purposes for the 2018 election cycle, and I would expect their total expenses for this election to be far greater than what was spent in 2017.

None of this spending counts any [legal cases](https://talkingpointsmemo.com/news/nra-gun-rights-cases) backed by the NRA, which is also a non-negligible amount of (arguably) political spending. It was estimated by one NRA spokesperson of them having around a $300 million annual budget for legal issues in 2014.

<sub>✝ The relative rankings I came up with is an apples to oranges comparison because I am including outside expenditures of the NRA but not any of the others on that list, but I include it just to keep a sense of the scale of the spending.</sub>

Answer (score 5):

According to OpenSecrets.org, the National Rifle Association or [NRA in 2017](https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/clientsum.php?id=D000000082&year=2017) spent $5,122,000.  This was not enough for it to make the list of the [twenty top spenders](https://www.opensecrets.org/lobby/top.php?indexType=s&showYear=2017), which required a minimum of $12,385,000 in 2017.

The NRA is generally considered powerful not because of how much money it gives but by how many people vote with them.  [The NRA is a powerful political force — but not because of its money.](https://www.vox.com/policy-and-politics/2017/10/5/16430684/nra-congress-money-no)

Comment: NRA spent ~$70m in the 2016 election. http://www.mcclatchydc.com/news/politics-government/article177312006.html

Comment: This answer is implying that's *the total* of what the NRA spends on swaying elections. This number is so far from the mark of the actual number that I'd say it's purposeful lying.

Comment: @blip This question relates to lobbying, which has a clear legal definition, it refers to contacting executive/legislative officials to push an agenda https://www.senate.gov/legislative/Lobbying/Lobby_Disclosure_Act/3_Definitions.htm .  The enormously inflated numbers that keeps getting thrown around is trying to include contacting voters as lobbying.  Rallying voters to a cause is as far from lobbying as you can get, and as Brythan pointed out, is the root of the NRA's power.

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades234 You are definitely correct, but a non-technical reader without that legal knowledge would be mislead by what is presented here.  Just explaining (in the answer) what is and is not included in this number should solve it though.

Comment: @indigochild I don't disagree that an explanation of the figure would help this answer, but I remain skeptical that an unbiased, non-technical reader would conflate standing on a soap box (ads of various kinds) and shouting <politician> is <against/for> our <cause> as lobbying.  Lobbying tends to be an effort to have an outsized impact on politics by purchasing favor from the executive/legislative branch, that favor proportional to money spent.  What the NRA is doing does have some need for money to get their message out, but is only as strong as the size of those that like their message.

Comment: I guess the thing is that there are two definitions of "lobby", the technical one that Brythan used in his answer, and the more "every day" definition which includes spending money or effort in general to achieve a political goal. I think both are fine to use as a basis of an answer, although the best possible answer should perhaps expand on this a bit.

Comment: @JackOfAllTrades234 be that as it may be, the omission of that from the answer makes this a poor answer IMO. Also note the question is pretty broad.

Comment: @Brythan The answer is based on data you decided to include or not include. If you don't feel the total amount the NRA spends on directly influencing elections has any bearing on "NRA spending" then that's your decision. I'm critiquing that decision.